# How do I add anchor text to a link in an HTML document I am building with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

All I want to be able to do is to create an HTML page with a list of links and names/text associated with that text.

E.g. `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`

Where I can change `Google` to be any text I want (including data from a variable).

I have this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
    doc.html {
        doc.body {
            contents.each do |i|
                doc.p {
                    doc.a(:href => list.first)
                    } 
            end         
            }           
        }
end
```

This just produces this:

```
<html><body><p><a href="someurl.com"></a></p></body></html>
```

What I want that to be though is:

```
<html><body><p><a href="someurl.com">First Link</a></p></body></html>
```

How do I do that in Nokogiri?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doc.a 'text_goes_here', :href => 'href_goes_here'
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually...just figured it out.

All I have to do is add `doc.text "First Link"`.

So the updated code snippet would look like this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
    doc.html {
        doc.body {
            contents.each do |i|
                doc.p {
                    doc.a(:href => list.first) {
                          doc.text "First Link"
                        }
                    } 
            end         
            }           
        }
end
```

Works like a charm.